# passed model of asp.net identiy user have wrong id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a very confusing issue ...

I have a controller called "UsersController" on that controller I list all asp.net identity users together with a link to edit each user. The view that list all users works and so does the view that bring up the detail about the user selected for edit. But the update view does not work. The passed model to the update method is not the one its supposed to be... when I look at the id passed on it does not match any user in the database... I have no clue of why?

Controller

```
    public ActionResult All()
    {
        var allUsers = _context.Users.ToList();
        return View(allUsers);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string userId)
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindById(userId);
        return View(user);
    }
    public ActionResult Update(ApplicationUser model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _userManager.FindById(model.Id);
            user.IsActive = model.IsActive;
            _userManager.Update(model);

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Edit view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form_section_search_id_mls" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="title_contanier">Aktiv: </h3>
                <div class="where-location">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- Begin .row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_submit_quick_search btn_submit_search pull-right" id="submitBtn" name="btn_submit_section_search_id_mls">Update user</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End .row -->

        </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: You're saying the Update method doesn't work but yet you post the Edit View.. How about the Update view?  Also, aren't you going to return the `user`? So `return View(user)`;

Comment: I haven't made the update view yet. In the edit view page I post to the update method and thats where I get a id that does not match any user.... I just wanted to check that the passed model is correct before I go on and create the update view. But even if I have not created that view the passed model should be correct right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never return entity models to the view. Always create an view model with just desired properties and pass that object instead. Consider following example:

```
public class UpdateUserViewModel
{
    public string ID {get; set; }
    // put properties that user could update  
    public bool IsActive {get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    var user = _userManager.FindById(id);
    return View(new UpdateUserViewModel
    {
        ID=user.Id,
        IsActive=user.IsActive
    });
}

public ActionResult Update(UpdateUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindById(model.ID);
        user.IsActive = model.IsActive;
        _userManager.Update(user);
    }
    // rest of codes
}
```

Also in the view you have to add `user.ID` as a hidden filed.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
```